# Using will_paginate with a has_many relationship in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, pagination

I've got the following models in my Rails app:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :pictures, :dependent => :destroy
end


class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  has_many :comments
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "800x800>", thumb: "225x225#" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/png"]
end
```

So a Post has_many Pictures. On my Post#index view, I use the following code to iterate through the posts and display the thumbnail for each of their pictures:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% post.pictures.each do |picture| %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to image_tag(picture.image.url(:thumb)), picture_path(picture)%>
      </li>
<% end %>
```

In order to limit the number of pictures displayed on each page, I'm attempting to implement pagination by using the following code in my Posts controller:

```
@pictures = @posts.pictures.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
```

This gives the following error:

```
undefined method `pictures' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc960f698a8
```

What am I doing wrong here? How could I fix this?

Also, I know it seems like it would be easier to just use the Pictures#index page, but I need this to work for other reasons.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please post your entire index method?

Comment: `@posts` is a collection of instances of `Post` but the `pictures` association is only available for a single instance of `Post`.  Are you trying to show all pictures for all posts, five per page?  If so, you might want to just generate a single flattened collection of post pictures and paginate that.

Comment: put the @pictures in Post#show action... instead of index.... it has to be @post.pictures.paginate(..)

Answer (score 1):

`@posts` is a relation (array-like object), and it doesn't have a method named `pictures`.

I'm not sure why you are paginating the pictures attached to each post on an index view, but you might be doing a carousel or something, so it may be valid, but if that's the case, you'll need to paginate in the view (or build a more complex data structure in your controller):

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <% post.pictures.paginate(:per_page => 5, page => params["post_#{post.id}_pictures_page"]).each do |picture| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to image_tag(picture.image.url(:thumb)), picture_path(picture)%>
    </li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You were actually correct in that I was approaching my problem entirely wrong to begin with. What I actually needed was to let Posts accept nested attributes for Pictures, then use the Pictures index and paginate that. Thanks for your help!